# how to clear a variable which is set from command line by "set /p var1="

Tags: batch-file

In Windows batch files, I accept variable from user input by `set /p var1=`, after `var1` is used, I don't know how to reset/clear its value.

If I don't reset/clear its value, when user meets `set /p var1=` again, and user enter directly. the previous input value will be still there. I don't want it, How to reset it for new user input?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To clear a variable, regardless how it was set:

```
set "var1="
```

Answer (score 0):

*rare issue, but you can try this:*

```
set "var=%var*=%"
```

Comment: What is the issue / Why the obfuscation? That simply expands to `set "var="`

Answer (score 0):

Different answers to original question were already provided above. One additional hint: within batch-script you can use the scopes:

```
setlocal
...
endlocal
```

This ensures that the variables are only accessible within your batch script and not affecting variables outside of your batch script (i.e. your variables are also not accessible outside of the batch script). By exiting of the batch script - the variables used locally get automatically "cleared".