# Set value and clear value in batch while reading from file in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to read from file and assign the read value to variable and perform a task.
However I see that I succeed in reading value correctly from file, however the assignment part doesn't work fine. Also I am struggling to clear the set value post assignment. I have looked at [SO-link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file) for reading and assigning value and [SO-link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106181/how-to-clear-a-variable-which-is-set-from-command-line-by-set-p-var1) for clearing the assigned value

Based on the link provided I added below line but it doesnt solve the problem

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

To add more my key file has numbers like below

12456

23890

45389

12690

Code Snippet:

```
for /F "delims=" %%x in (key.txt) do 
( 
echo value read from file -- %%x            **Shows correct value**
set "SERIAL=%%x"
echo number which got assigned -- %SERIAL%  **Shows incorrect value**
set "SERIAL="                               ** Doesnt clear the set value**
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set) (or unset, in your second problem's case).

Comment: @SomethingDark - I tried out the suggestion from the link but it doesn't help

Comment: That's because you did it wrong. I don't know what you ended up trying, but I can say with 100% certainty that you did not enable delayed expansion and then use `!SERIAL!` like you were supposed to.

Comment: Yes usage of !SERIAL! was missing along with delayed expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `enabledelayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%x in (key.txt) do ( 
  echo value read from file -- %%x
  set "SERIAL=%%x"
  echo number which got assigned -- !SERIAL!
  set "SERIAL=" 
)
```

For more on the subject, you can perform `setlocal /?` from `cmd.exe`

Comment: @OP: Note the position of the `(` after the `do` - it **must** be on the same physical line as the `do`. You need to invoke delayedexpansion [hundreds of SO articles about that - use the search feature] in order to display or use the run-time value of any string variable that's changed within a parenthesised series of instructions (aka "code block").

Comment: @Magoo - while editing for code, location of ( got shifted. Thanks for the pointer however.